# Basic PIE question appears to be wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

First-year math students were asked whether they experience math​ anxiety, headaches, or tiredness when studying for math exams. Of the 125 students​ asked, 66 experience math​ anxiety, 22 experience​ headaches, 51 experience​ tiredness, 10 get headaches and math​ anxiety, 22 get tired and experience math​ anxiety, 11 experience tiredness and​ headaches, and 17 fortunate students said they experience none of the three problems. How many of the students surveyed experience all three​ problems?

This is a basic PIE question i get 12 which is impossible.

$A=66 \space$,  $H=22\space$,  $T=51\space $,  $H\cap A = 10\space$,  $T \cap A= 22 \space,  T\cap H = 11$

$A\cup H\cup T = 125-17=108 $

$$A\cup H\cup T = A +H +T -  H\cap A -T \cap A \space -  T\cap H  + A\cap H \cap T$$

$$108=139-10-22-11+A\cap H \cap T$$

$$A\cap H \cap T = 12$$ Which is impossible as it is at most 10.

Comment: What is PIE? I assume you mean something different from $\pi$.

Comment: @Michael principle of Inclusion and Exclusion ?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem with the initial conditions.  I get $46$ with only math anxiety, $13$ with only headaches, $30$ with only tiredness, $10$ with math anxiety and tiredness only, $-2$ with math anxiety and headaches only, $-1$ with headaches and tiredness only, and $12$ with all three.

Comment: So then it was just a problem that used infeasible numbers.

Comment: It's possible to formulate this problem as a linear programming problem by choosing an objective function (which can be arbitrary), with the stated conditions as constraints.  I set the problem up in the Excel Solver using the simplex algorithm option, and the Solver said the problem is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

As has been discussed in the comments, the problem is indeed infeasible; your calculations are correct.